# Why am I Getting an Error with Returned JSON?

Tags: json, ruby

I'm reaching out to an API that returns `JSON` replies, either for success or failure.

Success:

```
{
"standard": {
    "staddress": "MANNING AVE",
    "stnumber": "533",
    "prov": "ON",
    "city": "Toronto",
    "confidence": "1"
  },
  "Dissemination_Area": {
    "adauid": "35200270",
    "dauid": "35200913"
  },
  "longt": "-79.414400",
  "TimeZone": "America/Toronto",
  "postal": "M6G2V8",
  "AreaCode": "647,416",
  "latt": "43.660453"
}
```

Failure:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 006,
    "message": "Request Throttled. Visit Geocoder.ca to obtain an authentication code."
  }
}
```

I'm using `Ruby 2.7.0` and I'm trying to parse the failure, which throws an error:

```
ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/json-2.3.1/lib/json/common.rb:263:in `parse': 784: unexpected token at '{ (JSON::ParserError)
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 006,
    "message": "Request Throttled. Visit Geocoder.ca to obtain an authentication code."
  }
}
```

- How can I get this failure to parse properly?
- Why am I getting this error?

I'm thinking the structure of the returned `JSON` would be sufficient, but a result code in the header might be derailing this, but I've seen nothing.

Comment: Good eye.  I completely missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is invalid. `006` is not a valid number because it is neither an integer nor a float.

You might want to ask the provider of the API to fix their responses in cases like that to either the integer `6` or the string `"006"`